# Inheriting a build plugin from parent POM conditionally

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

I have a multi-module build that produces several executable JAR's. Each of the sub modules have a plugin defined in the POM, `maven-dependency-plugin`, that copy all necessary dependencies to a localized folder in the `target` directory. Here is what that looks like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I would like to move this into my parent POM and only activate the plugin when the sub module is an executable JAR. What would be the best approach to accomplish this? Ideally, if possible, it would be nice to define a `<property>` in each executable sub module that would inherit the plugin when the property is present.

Comment: First why are you copying into a folder ? and why not using a packaging plugin? What kind of project do you have ? jar/wars?

Comment: @khmarbaise It is a JAR. There is an installer that collects all dependencies that are needed for each component to run and it was easier to collect these JAR's via a build step. If there is a better approach, I am all ears.

Comment: I would suggest to use maven-assembly-plugin which can create directly an archive (jar, ear, zip, tar.gz etc.) so this would be easier. Furthermore I would separate building the application jar files and the installers...meaning make separate modules to create the appropriate installers. Separation of concerns.